# Daf Hayomi on Tur/Beit Yosef/

Tags: halacha, tur

Shalom:)!
If there is some luach for learning Daf yomi Tur/Beit Yosef?
Or maybe someone luach for machsor of learning Tur/Beit Yosef for this year?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Moishy and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: You could always just get your Tur/BY and learn a daf every day... Another idea: many of the one volume Shulchan Aruch's have luchot for going over the whole SA in 1, 3, or 4 years. I personally have this one https://seforimcenter.com/Shulchan-Aruch-in-ONE-VOLUME__p-13082.aspx. The length of a siman in the Shulchan Aruch is often roughly proportional to the length of the Beit Yosef so you could use that as a rough proxy if you wanted to chazir the whole BY in that amount of time.

Comment: **לוח יומי ללימוד טור בית יוסף** https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/22946/p/1/t/1/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c

Comment: See discussions here: https://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=42273 and here: https://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=48256